# MySQL - Discord - Post table/results

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord

I have a code that pulls only 1 result and I need it to pull all results (or limit it to 10). Can someone help me out please or point me in the right direction?

```js
con.query(`SELECT * FROM events WHERE closed = 'No'`, (err, rows) => {
     if (err) throw err;

     let sql;
     let eventID = rows[0].eventnumber;
     let hostID = rows[0].host;
     let description = rows[0].eventname;
     let participants = rows[0].participants

     const event = `Event ${eventID}: ${description} - Hosted by: <@` + hostID + `>. Participants: ${participants}`

     const listEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setColor('#ff6600')
         .setTitle('Events')
         .setDescription(`${event}`)


     message.channel.send(listEmbed);

     con.query(sql);
 });
```

The information from the database is as below:

| eventnumber | host | eventname | closed | participants |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | Yes | test0 test1 |
| 17 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | No | test2 test3 test4 |
| 18 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | No | test5 test6 test7 |
| 19 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | Yes | test0 test1 |
| 20 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | No | test2 test3 test4 |
| 21 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | No | test5 test6 test7 |
| 22 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | Yes | test0 test1 |
| 23 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | No | test2 test3 test4 |
| 24 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | No | test5 test6 test7 |
| 25 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | Yes | test0 test1 |
| 26 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | No | test2 test3 test4 |
| 27 | 123456789012345678 | test raid | No | test5 test6 test7 |

EDIT:

So I found a way to make it show 10 events but it looks ugly and I know there is a better way just can't seem to figure it out. Also if there are not 10 results that meet the condition, the code errors out.

```js
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM events WHERE closed = 'No'`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        let sql;
        let firstID = rows[0].eventnumber;
        let firstHost = rows[0].host;
        let firstDescription = rows[0].eventname;
        let firstParticipants = rows[0].participants;
        let secondID = rows[1].eventnumber;
        let secondHost = rows[1].host;
        let secondDescription = rows[1].eventname;
        let secondParticipants = rows[1].participants;
        let thirdID = rows[2].eventnumber;
        let thirdHost = rows[2].host;
        let thirdDescription = rows[2].eventname;
        let thirdParticipants = rows[2].participants;
        let fourthID = rows[3].eventnumber;
        let fourthHost = rows[3].host;
        let fourthDescription = rows[3].eventname;
        let fourthParticipants = rows[3].participants;
        let fifthID = rows[4].eventnumber;
        let fifthHost = rows[4].host;
        let fifthDescription = rows[4].eventname;
        let fifthParticipants = rows[4].participants;
        let sixthID = rows[5].eventnumber;
        let sixthHost = rows[5].host;
        let sixthDescription = rows[5].eventname;
        let sixthParticipants = rows[5].participants;
        let seventhID = rows[6].eventnumber;
        let seventhHost = rows[6].host;
        let seventhDescription = rows[6].eventname;
        let seventhParticipants = rows[6].participants;
        let eigthID = rows[7].eventnumber;
        let eigthHost = rows[7].host;
        let eigthDescription = rows[7].eventname;
        let eigthParticipants = rows[7].participants;
        let ninethID = rows[8].eventnumber;
        let ninethHost = rows[8].host;
        let ninethDescription = rows[8].eventname;
        let ninethParticipants = rows[8].participants;
        let tenthID = rows[9].eventnumber;
        let tenthHost = rows[9].host;
        let tenthDescription = rows[9].eventname;
        let tenthParticipants = rows[9].participants;

        const firstEvent = `**Event ${firstID}:** ${firstDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + firstHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${firstParticipants}`
        const secondEvent = `**Event ${secondID}:** ${secondDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + secondHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${secondParticipants}`
        const thirdEvent = `**Event ${thirdID}:** ${thirdDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + thirdHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${thirdParticipants}`
        const fourthEvent = `**Event ${fourthID}:** ${fourthDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + fourthHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${fourthParticipants}`
        const fifthEvent = `**Event ${fifthID}:** ${fifthDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + fifthHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${fifthParticipants}`
        const sixthEvent = `**Event ${sixthID}:** ${sixthDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + sixthHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${sixthParticipants}`
        const seventhEvent = `**Event ${seventhID}:** ${seventhDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + seventhHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${seventhParticipants}`
        const eigthEvent = `**Event ${eigthID}:** ${eigthDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + eigthHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${eigthParticipants}`
        const ninethEvent = `**Event ${ninethID}:** ${ninethDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + ninethHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${ninethParticipants}`
        const tenthEvent = `**Event ${tenthID}:** ${tenthDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + tenthHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${tenthParticipants}`

        const listEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ff6600')
            .setTitle('Events')
            .setDescription(`${firstEvent}\n\n${secondEvent}\n\n${thirdEvent}\n\n${fourthEvent}\n\n${fifthEvent}\n\n${sixthEvent}\n\n${seventhEvent}\n\n${eigthEvent}\n\n${ninethEvent}\n\n${tenthEvent}`)


        message.channel.send(listEmbed);

        con.query(sql);
    });
```

I really would appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add a .forEach so that it will post once for each event. Flood protection may be needed.

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM events WHERE closed = 'No'`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        rows.forEach(row => {
            const eventID = row.eventnumber;
            const eventHost = row.host;
            const eventDescription = row.eventname;
            const eventParticipants = row.participants

            const event = `**Event ${eventID}:** ${eventDescription}\n**Hosted by:** <@` + eventHost + `>\n**Participants:** ${eventParticipants}`

            const listEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#ff6600')
                .setTitle('Events')
                .setDescription(`${event}`)

            message.channel.send(listEmbed);
        });
    });
```